# Generalize a function call for a collection of functions with differing number/type of parameters?

Tags: c++, c++11

I understand that the title is a bit of a mouthful, but sometimes a question is not only hard to answer but also hard to ask. Let me try to explain with examples. I'm not sure if this is a tough problem, or if I just don't know enough to answer it quickly. Here we go.

Consider that I have a collection of functions. I'll write out three sample ones:

```
double foo();
void bar(int q);
std::string vex(double p, int d);
```

I want to write code so that I can call any three of these functions, given the name of the function and its arguments by user decision. So let's assume there's an input like:

```
>bar [4]
```

How can I write code that takes this input and calls the respective function, while still being general enough to handle any other input, such as:

```
>foo []
>vex [5.2, 3.923]
```

At the moment, I am considering the idea of rewriting my collection of functions to take a vector of std::string arguments, and have *function specific code to convert these elements*:

```
void pisces(std::vector<std::string> args){ //params: int g, double f,   
                                            //std::string p
    /* Handle the params */
    int g = std::stoi(args[0]);
    double f = std::stod(args[1]);
    std::string p = args[2];

    /* do work with them here */
}
```

However this seems kind of like a cheat and I want to use a more generalized and eloquent solution if there is one.

Any ideas?

Comment: You could use any of a large number of existing script engines, rather than trying to invent one of your own (which is what you are doing here). [Lua](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lua_(programming_language)) is often recommended for ease of integration with a C[++] program.

Comment: You can use a variant type that can contain a variety of different types so that you don't need to put parsing in the individual functions. There's no better way to hold them than a vector though. The same variant type can be used for the return value.

Comment: Igor, what exactly is a "script engine"? I'm not too experience in C++ and am unaware.

Comment: Mark, that seems alright, but I feel like it may be easier to just stick with the set up I have currently. Is there really no other solution you can think of?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scripting_language

Comment: Ah, I didn't realize a script engine and a scripting language was the same thing! Thanks!